# Proving $\int_0^1|f(x)|\,dx\leq\frac12$, for continuous $f$ with $|\max f(x)-\min f(x)|\leq 1$ and $\int_0^1f(x)dx=0$

Tags: real-analysis, interpolation

> Let $f$ be continuous on $[0,1]$, and $M=\max\limits_{x\in[0,1]}f(x)$, $m=\min\limits_{x\in[0,1]}f(x)$, $|M-m|\leqslant1$,$\int_0^1f(x)\mathrm{d}x=0$.Prove that
> $$\int_0^1|f(x)|\mathrm{d}x\leqslant\frac{1}{2}$$

This is the homework assigned by the teacher. I have a little idea now:From Cauchy inequality,we have $$\int_0^1|f(x)|\mathrm{d}x\leqslant\left(\int_0^1f^2(x)\mathrm{d}x\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$
Then, we can know from the question that$(f-m)(f-M)\leqslant0$,so
$$\int_0^1(f-m)(f-M)\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1f^2(x)\mathrm{d}x+Mm\leqslant0\implies\int_0^1f^2(x)\mathrm{d}x\leqslant-Mm.$$
But I don't know what to do next...

Comment: This does not give you the correct bound but maybe you can use it to come up with the correct solution (I don't see how just now).

Use Young inequality:
$$
0 \leq -Mm \leq \frac{1}{2} M^2 + \frac{1}{2}m^2 = \frac{1}{2}(M-m)^2 +mM \leq \frac{1}{2}(M-m)^2
$$
(note that $m \leq 0 \leq M$ and thus $mM \leq 0$).

Then using what you already wrote:
$$
\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)| \mathrm{d} x \leqslant\left(\int_{0}^{1} f^{2}(x) \mathrm{d} x\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq (-Mm)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|M-m| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

Comment: @Lassadar Thank you. It's a good angle

Comment: Assuming just integrable, we can deduce that $\int_0^1 |f| \leqslant 1$. Indeed, write $f = f^+ - f^-$ in the standard way and conclude that $f^+ \leqslant M$ and $f^- \leqslant -m$. Summing up gives $|f| \leqslant M - m$ and then integrate from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: @Aryaman Maithani. The counterexample does not work because $\int_{0}^{1}|f|=1/4+1/4=1/2$.

Comment: @ Aryaman Maithani. Okay, I am convinced now. Your second comment are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Let $I^+=\{x:f(x)>0\}$ and $I^-=\{x:f(x)<0\}$.  Assume that $\mu(I^+)=\delta$ where
$\mu$ stands for the Lebesgue measure of the set $I^+$. Then $\mu(I^-)\leq 1-\delta$.
Write
$$J:=\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|dx=\int_{I^+}|f(x)|dx+\int_{I^-}|f(x)|dx$$
Now, since
$$\int_{I^+}|f(x)|dx\leq M \delta$$
and
$$\int_{I^-}|f(x)|dx\leq -m (1-\delta)$$
(becasue on $I^{-}$, $0\geq f\geq m$ $\implies$ $|f|=-f\leq -m$ )
then
$$J\leq M \delta-m (1-\delta).$$
But $|M-m|\leq 1$ which means $-m\leq 1-M$.
So
$$J\leq M \delta+(1-M) (1-\delta).$$

Minimize the function $H(M,\delta):=M \delta+(1-M) (1-\delta)$
in $\delta$ and $M$ on $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ (solve simultaneously the equations  $\frac{\partial H}{\partial M} =0,\; \frac{\partial H}{\partial \delta} =0$). You find that the minimize values are $M=\delta=\frac{1}{2}$. Hence

$$J\leq\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: $I^\pm$ need not be intervals, so $\mu$ would have to really be their measure.

Comment: Also, one of $I^+$ or $I^-$ must include $f(x) = 0$ in the definition, otherwise $\mu(I^+) + \mu(I^-) = 1$ need not be true.

Comment: (1) Both $I^{\pm}$ are intervals by the continuity of $f$. (2) Again by the continuity of $f$ I can split the integral at the point $c$ where $f(c)=0$.

Comment: (1) $f$ is continuous, not necessarily injective. Consider something like $\sin(100\pi x)$ to see that they need not be intervals. (2) Moreover, $f$ can be $0$ on a set of positive measure. It is easy to come up with an example.

Comment: Again, by continuity of $f$, if a set  $\{x:f(x)=0\}$  has a positive measure then it will be an interval. Then $I^{\pm}$ would be union of intervals !

Comment: Firstly, my comments (1) and (2) were separate. I wasn't saying that both can happen at the same time. But they actually can. Consider $\sin(8 \pi x)$ on $[0, 1/4] \cup [3/4, 1]$ and $0$ elsewhere. Here, $I^\pm$ are both not intervals and $f$ is $0$ on a set with measure $1/2$.

Comment: Note that continuity only takes intervals to intervals. The preimage of an interval can very well not be interval. (In general, replace "interval" with "connected".)

Comment: Let me ask you this: If I made the unimportant merely technical change of the word $interval$ into $set$, would you and the people keen on upvoting your such comments consider upvoting  my answer ?

Comment: No, because you'd still have one error remaining.

Comment: And  lenght into Lebesgue measure. Deal ?

Comment: No, you're still ignoring that $\{x : f(x) = 0\}$ can have positive measure.

Comment: No, I edited $\mu(I^{-})\leq 1-\delta$.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't read that. Anyway, I still can't talk on the behalf of those who liked my comments.

Comment: Thank you. I am looking forward for the upvotes of the other enthusiastic readers

Comment: @Medo The answer is clear. One suggestion is that you can add a range for $\delta$ when you optimize it. $\delta$ should be in [0,1].

Comment: @Zhiyan Thanks. Yes, and the same restriction applies to $M$ too. Edited

Comment: It is not true that $H$ is maximized at $M=\delta=\frac12$. In fact, $H(1,1)=1>H(1/2,1/2)$. Something else needs to be changed...

Comment: @ Maximilian Janisch. Oops. Minimize rather than maximize...edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Call $\mathcal D^+ = \{x\in[0,1]: f(x)\geq 0\}$ and $\mathcal D^- = \{x\in[0,1]: f(x)<0\}$.

Suppose $M = 1-\varepsilon$, so that $-m\leq \varepsilon$.

Since
$$\int_0^1 f(x) dx = \int_{\mathcal D^+} f(x)dx + \int_{\mathcal D^-} f(x)dx=0$$
we must have
$$\int_{\mathcal D^+} f(x)dx =- \int_{\mathcal D^-} f(x)dx.$$
Also
$$\int_0^1 |f(x)| dx = 2\int_{\mathcal D^+} f(x)dx = -2\int_{\mathcal D^-} f(x)dx.$$

Suppose, by contradiction,
$$\int_{\mathcal D^+} f(x)dx >\frac14.$$
This implies
$$\frac14 < - \int_{\mathcal D^-} f(x)dx \leq\varepsilon \int_{\mathcal D^-}dx = \varepsilon \left(1-\int_{\mathcal D^+} dx\right).$$
Thus
$$\int_{\mathcal D^+} dx < 1-\frac1{4\varepsilon}.$$
Recalling that $f(x) \leq 1-\varepsilon$, we obtain
$$\frac14 < \int_{\mathcal D^+} f(x)dx \leq (1-\varepsilon)\left(1-\frac1{4\varepsilon}\right).$$
The last inequality is equivalent to
$$-\frac{(2\varepsilon-1)^2}{4\varepsilon}>0,$$
which is impossibile. The thesis follows.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple probabilistic proof.

Consider the uniform distribution over $[0,1]$. By assumption
$E[f]=\int^1_0 f(x)\,dx =0$. If $\alpha \leq f\leq \beta$ almost surely on $[0,1]$, then $f\in L_2$ and
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(f)=E[(f-E[f])^2]=\int^1_0(f(x)-E[f])^2\,dx\leq\frac{(\beta-\alpha)^2}{4}\tag{0}\label{0}
\end{align}$$
This follows from the fact that
$$\begin{align}
E[f]=\operatorname{arg}\min_{r\in\mathbb{R}}E\big[(f-r)^2\big]\tag{1}\label{1}\end{align}$$

By assumption, $\alpha=\min(f)$ and $\beta=\max(f)$ satisfy $\beta-\alpha\leq1$. An application of Cauchy-Schwartz yields
$$\|f\|_1\leq\|f\|_2=\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(f)}\leq \frac{\beta-\alpha}{2}\leq \frac12$$.

---

**A few details:**

The well known equation \eqref{1} follows from
$$\begin{align}
E[(f-r)^2]&=E\Big[\big(f-E[f]+(E[f]-r)\big)^2\Big]\\
&=E\big[(f-E[f])^2\big]+\big(E[f]-r\big)^2\geq E\big[(f-E[f])^2\big]]
\end{align}$$

Inequality \eqref{0} then follows by taking $r=\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$, for this gives
$$\operatorname{Var}(f)\leq E[(f-r)^2]\leq\frac{(\beta-\alpha)^2}{4}$$